# Formatting Date according to regional settings in VBA

Tags: vba, date, outlook

I am extracting several dates from an e-mail body. 
It is random, so it could be a date in English, Spanish or some other format.

I need to get this date and convert it to the user's profile date settings.

```
E.g:         **User profile is English language**
             I receive  15/jun/2015  or  15-junio-2015 or 15/06/2015 
             The output jun/15/2015  or  june-15-2015  or 06/15/2015
```

What would be the easiest way to do such task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) functon available in VBA helpful. But I think it may not help in case of other languages, you will need to use the [DateValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d6k22a5(v=vs.90).aspx) function which returns a Date value containing the date information represented by a string, with the time information set to midnight (00:00:00).